# Could implicitly closing data connection in VB.Net cause a performance issue?

Tags: .net, database-connection, dataprovider

language: VB.Net and ASP.Net
Database: Oracle

In my programming, System.Data.Common.DbConnection.Close is only called through the descontructor of data Provider object, which might cause some connections won't be released untill garbage collector recycles the object. Will those connections which are not used any more but still alive cause an performance issue in online environment - TCP connections are full?

Thanks

Comment: What is `descontructor` I've never heard such thing?

Comment: The rule of scale is acquire a resource as late a possible and release it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are people that feel a using is absolutely required so dispose is explicitly called.
I happen to like try catch finally  just call  close() in the finally as I have found it does all necessary cleanup. 
Can I prove it -  I have data loading utilizes the run 24/7. 
There are numerous examples in MSDN with this pattern. 
For DB I like try catch finally over using.

But I don't think close in the dispose is delayed to garbage collection. 
A using block will call dispose and close is executed at that time.

[Establishing the Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254507(v=vs.100).aspx)

> You can also use the Close or Dispose methods of the connection object
>   for the provider that you are using. Connections that are not
>   explicitly closed might not be added or returned to the pool.

Don't just let is go out of scope.

- try/catch/finally and close in finally
  or
- using